# Dynamically changing button size

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, compact-framework

I'm using .NET CF with Visual Studio 2008.

In autogenerated Form.Designer.cs there is following code to specify button dimensions:

```
this.buttonX.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 24);
```

But when I use even the same code in my constructor dimensions "freak out" and button is much smaller.

```
public FormX()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.buttonX.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 24);
}
```

As seen on screenshots, left side works fine and on the right side I changed the dimensions from my constructor and the button is smaller...

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, button is created in designer view, and i'd like to change the button size(just size) dynamically afterwards.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by AutoScaling.  Your development machine has different DPI settings than your device.  In the generated code, the development DPI settings are actually stored, and this is used to scale the height and width of your controls via a comparison to the device DPI.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode(v=vs.90).aspx for more information, plus there are a lot of articles on this topic as well.

You can change the AutoScaleMode and manage all the sizes yourself like shown here ([How to make compact framework custom controls AutoScale aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153853/how-to-make-compact-framework-custom-controls-autoscale-aware)), or you can apply the same size adjustments the framework is doing when you manually adjust your control sizes.

---

If the control already exists and you are just trying to adjust its size, you can still scale the size yourself, similiar to what was done in some of the linked articles.

Something like this (free-0hand, not syntax-checked):

```
SizeF scale = this.AutoScaleFactor;
Size desiredSize = new Size(96, 24);
SizeF calculatedSize = new SizeF(desiredSize.Width * scale.Width, desiredSize.Height * scale.Height);
this.buttonX.Size = calculatedSize.ToSize();
```

Comment: When i tried the solution provided by @Damon8or in the link you provided, this is what happened: http://take.ms/hn8oH.

Also i tried to manually call `buttonX.Scale()` like @Heinzi provided in his question and that resulted in correct button size, but threw the button off the screen..

My problem is that Form.cs handles sizes differently than in Form.Designer.cs which is auto-generated by visual studio designer view..

Comment: Take a look at the revision.  It utilizes `AutoScaleFactor` to determined the difference in the design-time vs run-time DPIs and just adjust the application of the new size.

Comment: Still same result... Just in case tried it with completely new and empty project. Created two buttons via designer view and changed second button dimensions from `Form1_Load` and still button goes smaller than intended... The dimensions in designer does match my pda's screen resolution..

Comment: So you are saying that the AutoScaleFactor evalualted to 1.0 at runtome on the device?  What do you have your form's AutoScaleMode set to?  In your completely new and empty project, have a button-click that throws up a msgbox with the current size of the button and compare it to what the VS designer said it was.

Comment: And I find it unlikely that the DPI of your desktop monitor matches the DPI of your device, can you provide both of those values?

Comment: I can check it in an hour, will report back

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97942/discussion-between-kristian-and-tcarvin).